# Jssor Slider Bootstrap Compatibility

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm developing a website which is bootstrap compatible. In my website I'm also using a jssor image slider. The slider works perfectly but in bootstrap mode, it goes off to the right as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVXp8.png).

The slider works fine for me on normal web browsers but when I use the site on mobile devices or in bootstrap mode I face this problem.

For your reference I'm putting below the HTML code and jQuery code of the slider. All the necessary library files have been included.

```js
<script>
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {
            
            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
              [{b:0,d:600,y:-290,e:{y:27}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:185},{b:1000,d:500,o:-1},{b:1500,d:500,o:1},{b:2000,d:1500,r:360},{b:3500,d:1000,rX:30},{b:4500,d:500,rX:-30},{b:5000,d:1000,rY:30},{b:6000,d:500,rY:-30},{b:6500,d:500,sX:1},{b:7000,d:500,sX:-1},{b:7500,d:500,sY:1},{b:8000,d:500,sY:-1},{b:8500,d:500,kX:30},{b:9000,d:500,kX:-30},{b:9500,d:500,kY:30},{b:10000,d:500,kY:-30},{b:10500,d:500,c:{x:87.50,t:-87.50}},{b:11000,d:500,c:{x:-87.50,t:87.50}}],
              [{b:0,d:600,x:410,e:{x:27}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,o:1,e:{o:5}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,c:{x:175.0,t:-175.0}},{b:0,d:800,c:{x:-175.0,t:175.0},e:{c:{x:7,t:7}}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,x:-570,o:1,e:{x:6}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1,r:-180},{b:0,d:800,o:1,r:180,e:{r:7}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:80,e:{y:24}},{b:1000,d:1100,x:570,y:170,o:-1,r:30,sX:9,sY:9,e:{x:2,y:6,r:1,sX:5,sY:5}}],
              [{b:2000,d:600,rY:30}],
              [{b:0,d:500,x:-105},{b:500,d:500,x:230},{b:1000,d:500,y:-120},{b:1500,d:500,x:-70,y:120},{b:2600,d:500,y:-80},{b:3100,d:900,y:160,e:{y:24}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,o:-0.4,rX:2,rY:1},{b:1000,d:1000,rY:1},{b:2000,d:1000,rX:-1},{b:3000,d:1000,rY:-1},{b:4000,d:1000,o:0.4,rX:-1,rY:-1}]
            ];
            
            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $Idle: 2000,
              $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions,
                $Breaks: [
                  [{d:2000,b:1000}]
                ]
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
              }
            };
            
            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
            
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 500);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {
            
            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
              [{b:0,d:600,y:-290,e:{y:27}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:185},{b:1000,d:500,o:-1},{b:1500,d:500,o:1},{b:2000,d:1500,r:360},{b:3500,d:1000,rX:30},{b:4500,d:500,rX:-30},{b:5000,d:1000,rY:30},{b:6000,d:500,rY:-30},{b:6500,d:500,sX:1},{b:7000,d:500,sX:-1},{b:7500,d:500,sY:1},{b:8000,d:500,sY:-1},{b:8500,d:500,kX:30},{b:9000,d:500,kX:-30},{b:9500,d:500,kY:30},{b:10000,d:500,kY:-30},{b:10500,d:500,c:{x:87.50,t:-87.50}},{b:11000,d:500,c:{x:-87.50,t:87.50}}],
              [{b:0,d:600,x:410,e:{x:27}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,o:1,e:{o:5}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,c:{x:175.0,t:-175.0}},{b:0,d:800,c:{x:-175.0,t:175.0},e:{c:{x:7,t:7}}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,x:-570,o:1,e:{x:6}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1,r:-180},{b:0,d:800,o:1,r:180,e:{r:7}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:80,e:{y:24}},{b:1000,d:1100,x:570,y:170,o:-1,r:30,sX:9,sY:9,e:{x:2,y:6,r:1,sX:5,sY:5}}],
              [{b:2000,d:600,rY:30}],
              [{b:0,d:500,x:-105},{b:500,d:500,x:230},{b:1000,d:500,y:-120},{b:1500,d:500,x:-70,y:120},{b:2600,d:500,y:-80},{b:3100,d:900,y:160,e:{y:24}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,o:-0.4,rX:2,rY:1},{b:1000,d:1000,rY:1},{b:2000,d:1000,rX:-1},{b:3000,d:1000,rY:-1},{b:4000,d:1000,o:0.4,rX:-1,rY:-1}]
            ];
            
            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $Idle: 2000,
              $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions,
                $Breaks: [
                  [{d:2000,b:1000}]
                ]
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
              }
            };
            
            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
            
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 500);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/002.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="0" style="position: absolute; top: 320px; left: 30px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;"></div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/007.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="1" data-3d="1" style="position: absolute; top: -50px; left: 125px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">time lined layer animation</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/003.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="2" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: -380px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">finger catchable right to left</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/004.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="3" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">responsive, scale smoothly</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/005.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="4" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.6); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">image, text, and custom layers</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/006.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="5" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 600px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">tons of transition type</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/009.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="6" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">visual slider maker</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-b="0" data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/008.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position: absolute; top: -50px; left: 30px; width: 350px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(235,81,0,0.5); font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">play in and play out</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/011.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="8" data-3d="1" style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 150px; width: 250px; height: 250px; background-color: rgba(40,177,255,0.6); overflow: hidden;">-->
                    <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="9" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 25px; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 50px;">A Child Layer</div>-->
                <!--</div>-->
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/010.jpg" />
                <!--<div data-u="caption" data-t="10" data-3d="1" style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 100px; width: 250px; height: 250px; background-color: rgba(40,177,255,0.6);">
                    <div style="margin: 15px; font-size: 20px;">
                        <p>This is full customized content layer.<br />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Everything is allowed
                            
                        </p>
                        You can put
                        
                        <a href="http://wwww.jssor.com">
                            a link
                        </a> or an image
                        
                        <img src="img/icon_chrome.png" /> here.
                        
                    </div>
                </div>-->
            </div>
            <a data-u="ad" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Responsive Slider</a>
        
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;">
            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora02l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora02r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    </div>
```

Could anyone here help me style this properly so it is bootstrap compatible?

Answer (score 0):

With the code posted above, the slider will fit the width of parent container.
Please check the width of the parent container.